# Execute the button command if Dependency Property of the custom control is true

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

Custom Control.cs

```
public class CustomButtons: Control
  {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CmdExecProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(CmdExec), typeof(bool), typeof(CustomButtons), new PropertyMetadata("True"));

    public bool CmdExec
    {
      get => (bool)GetValue(CmdExecProperty);
      set => SetValue(CmdExecProperty, value);
    }
```

Generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                    xmlns:v="clr-namespace:ServicePageKit"
                    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
                    mc:Ignorable="d">
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/CompoundControlStyles.xaml" />
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

  <!--  Control template for a CustomButtons -->
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomButtonsTemplate"
                   TargetType="{x:Type v:CustomButtons}">
    <Grid Width="128"
          d:DesignHeight="200">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="52" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <Button x:Name="LoadButton"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Height="50"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              Command="{Binding CopyCommand}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Critical,
                                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                        AncestorType={x:Type v:CustomButtons}},
                                          Mode=OneWay}"
              Content="Copy"
              IsEnabled="true" />
      </Button>
    </Grid>
  </ControlTemplate>

  <Style x:Key="CustomButtonsStyle"
         TargetType="{x:Type v:CustomButtons}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource CustomButtonsTemplate}" />
  </Style>

  <Style TargetType="{x:Type v:CustomButtons}" BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomButtonsStyle}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Usage

```
 <kit:CustomButtons x:Name="SyskonButtons"
                          CmdExec="True"/>
```

This CustomControl works fine but I want that when CmdExec DepenpencyProperty is True, then the command (command names is used in Generic.xaml under Button) should execute, regardless the button is pressed or not.

Comment: You have already included Xaml Behaviors in ResourceDictionary and so you can use `InvokeCommandAction` and bind its `IsEnabled` property with CmdExec.

Comment: Still, I don't understand how to do it, you see my command is in the other file.

Comment: It is up to where your CopyCommand exists and where your CustomButtons is used.

Comment: What if I add ValuePropertyChange method.

and using the ICommand Property

CopyCommand.Excute(CopyCommand)  or I should change the ICommand property into method.